# how to set a pop list in the center of the screen

Tags: java, android

I want to set my pop list to the center of the screen both in horizontal and vertical  mode.

I have used the following code:

```
 android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams params=popupDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();    
 params.x=heightIndp-120;params.y=top;
 params.gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.LEFT;
```

Comment: write now it is coming at bottom left ?

Comment: yes, in the case of horizontal mode and bottom right in vertical mode

Comment: it is bottom right or buttom left..

Comment: bottom right in horizontal and bottom left in vertical

Comment: params.gravity=Gravity.Center you tried...

Comment: Can you tell me popupDialog which class object it is..

Comment: yes then it comes to right, on both mode

Comment: ok tell me which layout you are using...

Comment: I got it .i used this in my xml ,android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" thanx Bharath